# Does my formula work?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was just messing with numbers when I created this formula.

But to understand the formula, you have to understand this: Multiplication is repeated addition, as $8*6$ is more or less $8+8+8+8+8+8$, or vice-versa. In the same way, exponents are repeated multiplication, as $5^3$, can be written as $5*5*5$, which can be written as $(5+5+5+5+5)*5$, which can be written as $5+5 25$ times, or $25+25+25+25+25$, which is $125$

For the mathematicians out there, you would know what is tetration. $3↑↑↑3$ is $7,625,597,484,987$.

This formula is for calculating by decimals. For example, if want to calculate what $10^{1.5}$, it would be $10*(\sqrt10)$

For $10*1.5$, it would be $10+(10/2)$

Do you see the pattern yet?

I want to test if this works for tetration, pentation, sextation, and so on. But I couldn't find a calculator capable of doing these. So can the answerer please add the link to one of these calcs? I prefer online, but if there is none online, then a downloadable one will also work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you go beyond tetration you soon get huge numbers that cannot be fully calculated. Even in tetration this is the case , say $3\uparrow \uparrow 10$ is too large to be actually calculated. Apart from that , I do not understand what you actually ask.

Comment: Also , $3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow 3$ is $3\uparrow \uparrow 3^{27}$ , so a power tower with $3^{27}$ threes since three arrows already means pentation.

Comment: My bad. It is acctually (5+5+5+5+5)*5. I made a mistake